# Unity : How to delay between function calls?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, time

I've wrote a piece of code in c# that is supposed to prevent a function of being called to quickly, but it does not work, it currently calls the function over and over rapidly. Can you take a look at my code and see what's wrong or suggest another option ?

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Mouse0)) 
{
    if(timeToShoot < 0)
    {
        Fire();
        timeToShoot = (1 / fireRate);
    } 
    else
    {
        timeToShoot -= Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the value `timeToShoot = (1 / fireRate);` is too small, and is decremented too quickly, that's why it goes below zero, thus the function get called too quickly.

Try something like:

`timeToShoot = 20 * (1 / fireRate);`

Optionally: you might want to manipulate the factor `20` into a variable:

Somewhere in your global code:
`int factor = 20;`

then:

`timeToShoot = factor * (1 / fireRate);`

Comment: Nope, does not work. I set timeToShoot to 1000 and still nothing.

Comment: then try `timeToShoot = 100000` and see

Comment: if(timeToShoot < 0){
    fire();
    timeToShoot = 100000000000;
   }   
   else{
    timeToShoot -= 1;
   }              Yet still no result, defiantly not running anywhere near 100000000000ups...

Comment: something else is affecting the variable `timeToShoot` .. trying to log each change to see what other functions have access to it

Comment: I've noticed a pattern, timeToShoot only goes above 0 after I reload, but nothing else I have written affects timeToShoot, and I wrote everything in the script. Going to look into it.   OK, apparently everything after fire() didn't get ran, F**k knows why, but I've now fixed it, thanks!